# Defining Non-Scoped Text At Run-time C++

Tags: c++, winforms, scope

Is there an option of defining a text and using it later not as a string or anything, just as a part of a function **but being able to redefine it in the middle of the program (the definition to *not* take place in the preprocessor, but runtime)?** For example I have the following code in C++ Windows Forms:

```
private: System::Void ps1_GotFocus(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    if(this->ps1->Text == L"/ Your text here /") this->ps1->Text = L"";
    this->ps1->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromName( "Black" );
}

private: System::Void ps2_GotFocus(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    if(this->ps1->Text == L"/ Your text here /") this->ps1->Text = L"";
    this->ps2->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromName( "Black" );
}
```

where `ps1` and `ps2` are **TextBoxes** and I'm using it to display a **gray** 'Your text here' string and when clicked in the TextBox ready for input (when the TB `GotFocus`) to clear the text and make the input **black**. Having in mind that I have 9 TextBoxes like that, is it possible to make all this with less code? I tried the same code with `#define ps ps1` and a global `ps_GetFocus()` method outside everything that uses that ps, but as you know the `#define`s are done in the preprocessor and the last define (`ps ps9`) is defined even before the program is started.

Is there a way of defining non-scoped text at run-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have a common `ps_GotFocus` function for all your text boxes, and use `sender` (you'll have to cast it to the appropriate type first, not sure how to do that in .Net C++ with that weird `^` thingie, maybe `dynamic_cast` will work?) instead of the various `ps` objects.

Something along the lines of:

```
private: System::Void ps_GotFocus(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    TypeForYourTextBox^ the_sender = dynamic_cast<TypeForYourTextBox^>(sender);
    // I'm unsure about the previous line but you get the idea
    // You may also want to check that the cast succeeded, ie. the_sender is not null
    if (the_sender->Text == L"/ Your text here /") the_sender->Text = L"";
    the_sender->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::FromName("Black");
}
```

Comment: I have never used the event handlers' arguments before, this code works great, **thanks a lot**! And still, **out of curiosity**, is there a way of defining non-scoped text, other than with `#define`?

Comment: @Bonnev: Not in the sense you mean it. There are two other possibilities though: either a plain function/method that takes a text box reference as argument and that you would call from each of your various `pxX_GotFocus`, or a parametrized `#define` macro that you would, again, call from each of your various `pxX_GotFocus`. But, IMHO, either one is still a lot of useless code duplication (if only because all the required `psX_GotFocus` methods) so I find my `sender` solution cleaner (and in this kind of libraries, this is *exactly* why `sender` is here so you might as well use it ;)).